# Where's the Windows menu command to advance the desktop picture to the next one

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I seem to recall there being a command in the desktop context menu in Windows 7 that would advance the desktop slide show to the next picture in the sequence (when you have the desktop set up to show a slide show), but I don't see it nowadays. Can anyone tell me where that command is hiding now? My desktop slide show seems to be stuck on one of the pictures, and I'd like to use that command to give it a kick to get going again. (Or even if it still exists. It wouldn't surprise me to find out that Microsoft took that command away. It's not the first time that they've removed useful features from their software.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right click the desktop
Select "Next Desktop Background"

However, If you don't have multiple backgrounds selected you will not see the context menu "Next Desktop Background" The Context on the left has multiple backgrounds selected. the Context on the right has only a single background selected.  This feature exists in all windows versions up to 6.4 Build 9879 (windows 10)
[image]

Comment: You're right. I just went back into the settings and noticed that I only had one of the pictures in my slide show folder selected instead of all of them. :-(